# Grouping based on state change

Tags: sql, sql-server

Current table:

```
Name    State   Start  Time
A       Start   17/01 2pm
A       update  17/01 4pm
B       Start   18/01 3pm
B       Start   18/01 5pm
C       Start   18/01 6pm
B       Start   19/01 2pm
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
Name    StartTime   End Time
A      17/01 2pm    17/01 4pm
B      17/01 4pm    18/01 5pm
C      18/01 5pm    18/01 6pm
B      18/01 6pm    19/01 2pm
```

Can any one advise?

Comment: Is there any identity column ?

Comment: I can create this in view if that will help

Comment: Why B start with 4 PM ? it should be 3 PM ? or any special case should be considered .. you need to write all such cases

Comment: **Please** tell us which database this is for. "SQL"isn't enough to tell us what specific syntax is needed by your database.

Comment: SQL server 2014

Comment: Start time should pull from end time of previous row(I'm using orderby time )

Comment: Is [start] a date column and [time] a time column? or is [StartTime] a single datetime column? (& in future would you express date/time in yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss strings )

Comment: I don't follow your logic, perhaps this will help you or someone else:  http://rextester.com/GCOWW72321

Comment: In future try to provide sample data in a way that can be used as inserts easily. See  [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

according to your comments you should use window functions LAG or LEAD. take a look to the following sample code:

LAG: Accesses data from a previous row in the same result set.

LEAD: Accesses data from a subsequent row in the same result set.

```
with
    cte
as
(
    select
        [Name]  ,
        [State] ,
        lag(StartTime) over(order by [Name], [State], StartTime)    as StartTime    ,
        StartTime   as EndTime
    from
        dbo.Test
)
select
    [Name]                          ,
    [State]                         ,
    min(StartTime)  as StartTime    ,
    max(EndTime)    as EndTime
from
    cte
group by
    [Name]  ,
    [State]
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad for showing Lag function really handy one